# declaration error in C++ while string array declaration

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I declared string array like `string pdts[10];` But am getting declaration syntax error.Already i included  still am getting the same error. please help me to solve. 
my code is

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<string.h>
string pdts[10];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, if you are in c++ you should do like:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
```

Second, either use:

```
using namespace std;
```

Or, use fully qualified name `std::string`

Comment: ok, I will try and accept your answer

Comment: no,its not working.same error i am getting.

Comment: @Madhumitha what is the error exactly?

Comment: Declaration syntax error on "using namespace std" line

Comment: write in this way: http://ideone.com/JEXRih

Comment: @Madhumitha - Your usage of <iostream.h> -- are you using an ancient, obsolete compiler such as Turbo C++ or something from the early 1990's?

Comment: sorry. am new to c++.am using turbo C++ 3.0 version.how to check compiler version?

Comment: @Madhumitha - Please get a *modern* C++ compiler.  There are free ones out there that adhere to modern standards.  Why are you using this outdated compiler?  The reason for your error is understandable -- you're probably reading modern C++ books to learn from (which is good), but using an old compiler to write code (which is bad).

Comment: see @Madhumitha , I'd recommend gcc if you're in linux or if you're in windows use codeblock (if possible visual studio, the best. may seem complicated though)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie  I think my turbo c is problem.. I will try it new version.

Answer (score 1):

you should use:

```
using namespace std;
```

without it, it will give you an error.

Comment: Whilst this will work, you should avoid this whenever possible and fully qualify the name instead. Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)